# Remove String from Text Box from back

Tags: c#, string, textbox, keyboard, windows-phone

I have a requirement in C# where I have a text box with numbers delimited by `;` say e.g.
`(205)33344455;918845566778;`

Now when a user presses <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> (to remove the number) one character at a time gets deleted. I want to delete the whole number at once.

So when the user presses <kbd>←</kbd> the first time, the number will be highlighted
i.e. if text is `(205)33344455;918845566778;`, the `918845566778;` part will be highlighted in say black, and when the user presses <kbd>←</kbd> again the whole number i.e. `918845566778;` will be deleted.

So is it possible to highlight a particular section in text box, and delete the whole number?

I used a `for` loop like:

```
for{back=txtPhone.Text.Length;back<=txtPhone.Text.indexOf(';');back--)
```

But I was not able to achieve the desired result.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Also it would be great if a code is shown, in case the user wants to remove the number from between or so, not only back.
Sorry for this new query.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of methods to achieve want you want come to mind:

- Subscribing the text box to `Control.Keydown` event which would check for the <kbd>←</kbd> button and perform the highlight up to the last delimiter (;) using `TextBox.SelectionLength` meaning a <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> will clear it.

  ```
      private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Left)
              return;

          e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

          //Select up to previous delimeter (;) here
      }
  ```
- Use a listbox (or something similar) to store the delimited data as it is entered.  This will allow the user to select what they need, and remove it via a button you will provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your requirement as shown below

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0) return;

    if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) && (textBox1.SelectionLength == 0))
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, textBox1.Text.Substring(0,textBox1.Text.Length-1).LastIndexOf(';'));
        if (textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.SelectionStart, 1) == ";") textBox1.SelectionStart++;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length-textBox1.SelectionStart ;
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) && textBox1.SelectionLength >= 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.SelectionStart );
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also just one more query what if the user wants to remove a number from between or so, then this code could fail, cause we always try to get LastIndexOf(";").

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Select the token (i.e. number terminated by ;) that **contains** the cursor (method selectToken())
2. Remove it when backspace is
       pressed a second time

---

Example:
your textbox contains '(205)33344455; 918845566778; 8885554443;'

you click with the left mouse button between 9188455 and 66778; (second number)

then you press backspace

the string 918845566778; gets selected

you press backspace a second time and that string gets deleted

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Remove_String_from_Text_Box_from_back
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    //selects token that contains caret/cursor      
    private void selectToken() {
        string str0 = textBox1.Text;
        int caretPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        int tokenEndsAtIndex = str0.IndexOf(';', caretPosition, (textBox1.Text.Length - caretPosition));
        string prefix = "";
        if (tokenEndsAtIndex == -1)
        {
            tokenEndsAtIndex = str0.IndexOf(';');
        }

        prefix = str0.Substring(0, tokenEndsAtIndex);
        int tokenStartsAtIndex = 0;
        tokenStartsAtIndex = prefix.LastIndexOf(';');
        if (!(tokenStartsAtIndex > -1)) { tokenStartsAtIndex = 0; } else { tokenStartsAtIndex++; }
        textBox1.SelectionStart = tokenStartsAtIndex;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = tokenEndsAtIndex - tokenStartsAtIndex + 1;//may be off by one

    }
 private void selectLastToken(string str0)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\d()]*;)$");
            var capturedGroups = regex.Match(str0);

            int idx0 = 0;
            if (capturedGroups.Captures.Count > 0)
            {
                idx0 = str0.IndexOf(capturedGroups.Captures[0].Value, 0);
                textBox1.Select(idx0, textBox1.Text.Length);
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "(205)33344455;918845566778;";
            textBox1.Select(0, 0);
        }

        //selects last token terminated by ;
        private void selectTextOnBackSpace()
        {
            string str0 = textBox1.Text;
            int idx0 = str0.LastIndexOf(';');
            if (idx0<0)
            {
                idx0 = 0;
            }
            string str1 = str0.Remove(idx0);
            int idx1 = str1.LastIndexOf(';');
            if (idx1 < 0)
            {
                idx1 = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                idx1 += 1;
            }
            textBox1.SelectionStart = idx1;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = str0.Length - idx1;
        }


        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back )
            {
                if (textBox1.SelectionLength==0)
                {
                    selectToken();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you re-edited you answer. I tried the old solution given by you and it had work, though I had modified it a little bit, and I did get the answer.
But I am yet to try your new code, as I am not that well versed with regular expressions.

Comment: Also just one more query what if the user wants to remove a number from between or so, then this code could fail, cause we always try to get LastIndexOf(";").

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, do you mean that if the caret/cursor is between (205) and 33344455; you want that part of the number to be deleted? If that is the case you are right, this is not covered by my code, I will get youa new answer asap though. Thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: What I meant was that if there are 3 nos. say 
(205)33344455;
918845566778;
8885554443;
in the textbox.
Now if I want to delete the middle number i.e.918845566778, then how can I achieve the same.
Also when I press the backspace the first time ";" gets removed.
I hope you got my question.

Comment: You're welcome I have updated my question, in an effort to explain my solution better. Let me know what you think.